# Unable to import 'pandas_profiling' module

Tags: python, conda, pandas-profiling

I have installed 'pandas_profiling' through `conda install -c conda-forge pandas-profiling` in the base environment. I could see through the `conda list` that pandas_profiling has been installed correctly (snapshot attached),
[image]

When I try to `import pandas_profiling` I receive ModuleNotFoundError

```
import  pandas_profiling
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-4-60d2bac64bfc>", line 1, in <module>
    import  pandas_profiling

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas_profiling'
```

Update: output of `import sys; print(sys.path); print(sys.prefix)`

```
['/home/user1/miniconda3/lib/python38.zip', '/home/user1/miniconda3/lib/python3.8', '/home/user1/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload', '', '/home/user1/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages', '/home/user1/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/extensions', '/home/user1/.ipython']

/home/user1/miniconda3
```

Comment: How do you verify that the kernel running in IPython corresponds to the Conda environment where you installed the package? E.g., show us output of `import sys; print(sys.path); print(sys.prefix)`.

Comment: I have updated my quesstion, is it something to do with Build of 'pandas-profiling = 0', as seen in the list.

Comment: Can you try making a new environment, but forcing a newer version?  E.g., `conda create -n pp_test pandas-profiling=3 ipykernel`.

Comment: environment was not created `Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.`, `PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels: - pandas-profiling=3`

Answer (score 0):

This is a frequent issue, check out this entry in the [FAQ](https://pandas-profiling.github.io/pandas-profiling/docs/master/rtd/pages/support.html#conda-install-defaults-to-v1-4-1).

Answer (score 0):

Occasionally you will encounter this error if you import a package from the current notebook. It is important to ensure that the pip version is associated with the current Python kernel. That way, the installed packages can be used in the current notebook.

As detailed [here](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2017/12/05/installing-python-packages-from-jupyter/), the shell environment and the Python executable are disconnected.

This should work for you

```
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install pandas-profiling
```